# modify the text in file (millions of columns, tab-delimited) - delete all tabs except the first one and add new columns behind the final column

Tags: linux, perl, unix, sed, awk

Here, I want to have your helps on text file modification.

I want to modify the text in file (millions of columns, tab-delimited) - delete all tabs except the first one and add new columns behind the final column.

- the file (4 columns here, but
  millions of columns in my real file,
  tab-delimited) I have now:

  ```
  day1 1 3 7
  day7 2 4 8
  day3 2 5 6
  ```
- the file I want, delete the separator
  (from the second one), and add three
  new columns (one is the same as the
  first one, the other two with same
  values in all the same column, here x
  and y).

  ```
  day1 137 day1 x y
  day7 248 day7 x y
  day3 256 day3 x y
  ```

I intend to do that using awk, mixed with sed. But, I tried many different ways, I still do not how to do that.

Could you please give me any helps? Thanks in advance.

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gawk -f script.awk < input > output` where `script.awk` contains:

```
{
    old=$1;
    $0 = substr($0, length($1)+1);
    gsub(/[[:space:]]*/, "", $0);
    print old, $0, old, "x", "y";
}
```

See a live demo [here](http://www.ideone.com/gJUIx) (thank you [belisarius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353410/belisarius) for showing me this site)

Comment: Benoit, Thanks a lot for your kind help. It is really a well done. I learned much from you scripts. So cool, awk/gawk.

Answer (score 2):

The question is tagged [[perl]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl), so for completeness:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -lan

BEGIN { $, = "\t" }

$first = shift @F;
print $first, join("", @F), $first, qw/ x y /;
```

The program uses several convenience features to stay concise.

- setting `$,` to a TAB character, analagous to `FS` in awk
- the `-l` switch to implicitly add `"\n"` to each `print`, which works sort of like `ORS` in awk
- the [`-a`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-a*) (autosplit or awk mode) switch

> turns on autosplit mode when used with a `-n` or `-p`. An implicit `split` command to the `@F` array is done as the first thing inside the implicit while loop produced by the `-n` or `-p`.
>
> ```
> perl -ane 'print pop(@F), "\n";'
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> while (<>) {
>   @F = split(' ');
>   print pop(@F), "\n";
> }
> ```

- the [`-n`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-n*) switch to implicitly loop over all lines of input

> causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like `sed -n` or `awk`:
>
> ```
> LINE:
> while (<>) {
>   ...  # your program goes here
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/\t//2g;s/\(.*\t\)\(.*\)/&\t\1x\ty/' file
day1    137     day1    x       y
day7    248     day7    x       y
day3    256     day3    x       y
```

I'm guessing that as it's a tab separated file you want new columns to be tab separated. If not:

```
sed 's/\t//2g;s/\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/& \1 x y/' file
day1    137 day1 x y
day7    248 day7 x y
day3    256 day3 x y
```